# Is it possible to have two xlloop servers?

Tags: java, excel

I have two xlloop servers, which work when ran separately (on port 5454)

But when I run one of them on port 5454 and the other one on port 3030, I can only access functions exposed by the one on port 5454.

In the `\xlloop\bin` folder, where the `xlloop.xll` Excel addon file is, I created an `xlloop.ini` file, which contains this code:

```
providers=Java

[Java]
server=localhost,localhost:5353,localhost:5454,localhost:5252
```

In my server class I specify the port with: 
`FunctionServer fs = new FunctionServer(5353);`

Unfortunately only the one on 5454 is picked up, it looks like ini file is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you list servers like I did, you are supposed to list server providing the same functions.

I solved my issue with this ini setup:

```
providers=Java,Java2

[Java]
server=localhost:5454
function.name="M"

[Java2]
server=localhost:5353
function.name="H"
```